# Getting error "post-link script failed for package defaults ::ipykernel-4.10.0-py27_0" while installing ipykernel in anaconda with python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying to install ipykernel in a separate python 2.7 environment (py27) for use of jupyter notebook. My base environment uses python3.9 that works great. When trying to use `conda install ipykernel`, I get the error below. Yes, this was done in a separate environment from my base and I am not aware of any virus softwares that are impeding this from successfully completing. Those are the only answers that I've seemed to find online. I also tried reinstalling anaconda. I did not attach the output from `conda install -v ipykernel`, but saw an error saying invalid syntax in `decorator.py on line 162`. It was pointing to the `file=stderr` in a print function call.

Similar to this problem https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7351, but was unable to solve the problem with the suggestions.

````
(py27) C:\Users\Heath>conda install ipykernel
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\Heath\anaconda3\envs\py27

  added / updated specs:
    - ipykernel


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  backports          pkgs/main/noarch::backports-1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_2
  backports.shutil_~ pkgs/main/noarch::backports.shutil_get_terminal_size-1.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_3
  backports_abc      pkgs/main/noarch::backports_abc-0.5-py_1
  colorama           pkgs/main/noarch::colorama-0.4.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  decorator          pkgs/main/noarch::decorator-5.1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  enum34             pkgs/main/win-64::enum34-1.1.6-py27_1
  futures            pkgs/main/win-64::futures-3.3.0-py27_0
  ipykernel          pkgs/main/win-64::ipykernel-4.10.0-py27_0
  ipython            pkgs/main/win-64::ipython-5.8.0-py27_0
  ipython_genutils   pkgs/main/noarch::ipython_genutils-0.2.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1
  jupyter_client     pkgs/main/win-64::jupyter_client-5.3.4-py27_0
  jupyter_core       pkgs/main/win-64::jupyter_core-4.6.1-py27_0
  libsodium          pkgs/main/win-64::libsodium-1.0.16-h8b3e59e_0
  pathlib2           pkgs/main/win-64::pathlib2-2.3.5-py27_0
  pickleshare        pkgs/main/win-64::pickleshare-0.7.5-py27_0
  prompt_toolkit     pkgs/main/win-64::prompt_toolkit-1.0.15-py27h3a8ec6a_0
  pygments           pkgs/main/noarch::pygments-2.5.2-py_0
  python-dateutil    pkgs/main/noarch::python-dateutil-2.8.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pywin32            pkgs/main/win-64::pywin32-227-py27h0c8e037_1
  pyzmq              pkgs/main/win-64::pyzmq-18.1.0-py27hc56fc5f_0
  scandir            pkgs/main/noarch::scandir-1.10.0-pyh5d7bf9c_3
  simplegeneric      pkgs/main/win-64::simplegeneric-0.8.1-py27_2
  singledispatch     pkgs/main/noarch::singledispatch-3.7.0-pyhd3eb1b0_1001
  six                pkgs/main/noarch::six-1.16.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  tornado            pkgs/main/win-64::tornado-5.1.1-py27h0c8e037_0
  traitlets          pkgs/main/win-64::traitlets-4.3.3-py27_0
  wcwidth            pkgs/main/noarch::wcwidth-0.2.5-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  win_unicode_conso~ pkgs/main/win-64::win_unicode_console-0.5-py27hc037021_0
  zeromq             pkgs/main/win-64::zeromq-4.3.1-h2880e7c_3


Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(699): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::ipykernel-4.10.0-py27_0'.
Rolling back transaction: done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package defaults::ipykernel-4.10.0-py27_0
location of failed script: C:\Users\Heath\anaconda3\envs\py27\Scripts\.ipykernel-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>
==> script output <==
stdout:
stderr:
return code: 1

()```
````